# Why use getter for functions that use Moment.js? (vueJS, typescript)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, momentjs

`weekOfMonth()` returns this month and this week(week of this month)

```js
<template>
  <h3>{{ weekOfMonth }}</h3>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default class HomeView extends Vue {
  
  const moment = require("moment");
  
  private get weekOfMonth(): string {
    const nowDate = moment().utc(true);
    let week: number = nowDate.week() - moment(nowDate).startOf("month").week() + 1;
    return `This Month: ${nowDate.month() + 1} / This Week: ${week}`;
  }
}
</script>
```

result: This Month: 7 / This Week: 4

result when not using 'get' : function () { [native code] }

Why do I have to use getter to get the return value?

Comment: This is not specific to moment or vue. This is the [JavaScript getter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). If you don't put `get` in front of the function then it's a normal function and not a getter.

Answer (score 1):

the `getter` is called when you use it.
if you are trying to use the normal function, you need call it with `weekOfMonth()`, so try add parentheses like below

```
<template>
  <h3>{{ weekOfMonth() }}</h3>
</template>
```

Comment: The difference is that a getter is cached

Comment: @Estus Flask yes, you're right, and the getter will excute only when the dependencys changes, but function will excute everytime ui changes. So getter is recommended~